# Reorder bootstrap column on click function

Tags: html, jquery, arrays, bootstrap-5

I want to switch columns order using bootstrap and jQuery on click.

I've done this for the left button, but it doesn't work:

```js
$("#left").on("click",
    function() {
        $("#A").removeClass('order-1').addClass('order-2');
        $("#B").removeClass('order-2').addClass('order-1');
        console.log("1 done")
    }, 
    function() {
        $("#A").removeClass('order-2').addClass('order-1');
        $("#B").removeClass('order-1').addClass('order-2');
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="arrow position-absolute top-50 start-0 translate-middle-y ps-2" id="left">left</div>
<div class="arrow position-absolute top-50 end-0 translate-middle-y pe-2" id="right">right</div>


        <div class="col-6 bg-success d-flex align-items-end order-1" id="A">one
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-primary d-flex align-items-end order-2" id="B">two
        </div>
```

Comment: Why you put two functions to `.on` call? Signature: `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`. Fix event call and wrap your code to `$(document).ready()` and it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go...

There are a few problems.

1. You tagged this questions as `bootstrap-4`, but used `bootstrap-5` in your code.
2. Bootstrap classes `order-1` and `order-2` were not even working because you need to wrap `col` classes with a `row` class.
3. Use jQuery `toggleClass` to change classes.

See the snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".col-6").click(function() {
    $("#A").toggleClass("order-1 order-2");
    $("#B").toggleClass("order-2 order-1");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 bg-success d-flex align-items-end order-1" id="A">one</div>
  <div class="col-6 bg-primary d-flex align-items-end order-2" id="B">two</div>
</div>
```